# This code push Null notification

Tags: php, android, ajax, google-cloud-messaging

I have this code to push notification (GCM) but when i am trying to push notification i got null notification (the string of my message is missing)

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function sendPushNotification(id){
                var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
                $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "send_message.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                          $('.txt_message').val("");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container{
                width: 950px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
            }
            h1{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 24px;
                color: #777;
            }
            div.clear{
                clear: both;
            }
            ul.devices{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            ul.devices li{
                float: left;
                list-style: none;
                border: 1px solid #dedede;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 15px 25px 0;
                border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #555;
            }
            ul.devices li label, ul.devices li span{
                font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-style: normal;
                font-variant: normal;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #393939;
                display: block;
                float: left;
            }
            ul.devices li label{
                height: 25px;
                width: 50px;                
            }
            ul.devices li textarea{
                float: left;
                resize: none;
            }
            ul.devices li .send_btn{
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0096FF, #005DFF);
                background: linear-gradient(#0096FF, #005DFF);
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                border-radius: 3px;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once 'db_functions.php';
        $db = new DB_Functions();
        $users = $db->getAllUsers();
        if ($users != false)
            $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
        else
            $no_of_users = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="devices">
                <?php
                if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                                <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="send_container">                                
                                    <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                    <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    <?php }
                } else { ?> 
                    <li>
                        No Users Registered Yet!
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

send_message.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    echo "in send message class";

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

GcmIntentService.java

```
package com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    String TAG="pavan";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        Log.d("pavan","in gcm intent message "+messageType);
        Log.d("pavan","in gcm intent message bundle "+extras);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

                String recieved_message=intent.getStringExtra("text_message");
                sendNotification("message recieved :" +recieved_message);

                Intent sendIntent =new Intent("message_recieved");
                sendIntent.putExtra("message",recieved_message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sendIntent);

            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark)
                        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.